# ssl validation error coming while doing chef client setup

Tags: validation, ssl, chef-infra, nodes

I am fairly new to Chef and have installed a chef server 11 on Node1, I have done successfully setup for workstation on Node2 and when I get user list I am getting all the user list

```
[root@Staging3 .chef]# knife user list
admin
root
```

But when I issue knife bootstrap I am getting following error.

```
[root@Staging3 .chef]# knife bootstrap 10.4.6.214 -x root -N slave1 --sudo
Doing old-style registration with the validation key at /opt/chef/chef-repo/.chef/chef-validator.pem...
Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead

Connecting to X.X.X.X
root@X.X.X.X's password: 
X.X.X.X Starting first Chef Client run...
X.X.X.X Starting Chef Client, version 12.1.1
X.X.X.X Creating a new client identity for slave1 using the validator key.
X.X.X.X [2015-03-19T00:42:00+05:30] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: staging4.akosha.com - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
X.X.X.X 
X.X.X.X ================================================================================
X.X.X.X Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "slave1"
X.X.X.X ================================================================================
X.X.X.X 
X.X.X.X [2015-03-19T00:42:00+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
X.X.X.X Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 6.045009421 seconds
X.X.X.X [2015-03-19T00:42:00+05:30] ERROR: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
X.X.X.X [2015-03-19T00:42:00+05:30] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I have read all the blog for doing client setup but haven't came across any solution, Any help would be appreciated in this....

I thought there might be some problem from my chef workstation but it wasn't

```
[root@Staging3 chef-repo]# knife ssl check -s https://staging4.akosha.com
Connecting to host staging4.akosha.com:443
Successfully verified certificates from `staging4.akosha.com'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is some info here you can look at:

https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_security.html

With Chef 12 you need to run the command:

```
knife ssl fetch
```

Alternately you can turn of ssl verification in the knife.rb file with this setting:

```
ssl_verify_mode    :verify_none
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanx for your reply, I did run knife ssl fetch on my workstation and it worked correctly . The problem is with the dumb slave(client).

Comment: Helped me as temporary solution for local Chef playground. Personally I do not recommend to switch off verification at production.

Answer (score 12):

Your target node does not know your chef server certificate and can't validate it.

You'll have to add the chef-server cert to the client.

I think the bug is still open about knife not pushing the trusted_certs directory to bootstraping nodes.

Workaround for now, bootstrap with `--node-ssl-verify-mode none` so the chef client will not verify ssl (and it will write the `ssl_verify_mode :verify_none` to node's `client.rb` IIRC)

After that  you'll be able to use a cookbook to push the chef-server certificate and configure the ssl parameters with `chef-client` cookbook for exemple.

Comment: thanx brother. I got ur way and it worked fine for me. One more question is there any way I can run a recipe on the client from server itself. Sorry if I am asking a useless question

Comment: Chef is a pull model, the chef-client run on the node an ask the server for it's runlist. There's a lot of way to fire the chef-client on the node, one of them being `knife ssh` from the workstation. In chef 12 there's also the `push-job` addon (free under 25 nodes, license asked for more)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo knife ssl fetch

// adding
ssl_verify_mode    :verify_none
```

to workstation's knife.rb file worked for me.

those of you who use AWS ubuntu , make sure you are using public DNS of you of chef-server in knife.rb file

Answer (score 1):

Install chef-client

```
sudo knife client create chef-client -a -f "/etc/chef/client.pem" -e vi
knife bootstrap 192.168.yy.xxx -x vagrant -P vagrant --sudo
```

from chef-server

```
scp /etc/chef/client.pem chef-server:/etc/chef/
```

on chef-server

```
mkdir -p ~/.chef/trusted_certs
sudo cp /var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/chef-server.crt ~/.chef/trusted_certs
```

on the client, fetch the cert to the same location

```
mkdir -p ~/.chef/trusted_certs
knife ssl fetch
```

If that fails, from the client, run

```
scp chef-server:/home/vagrant/.chef/trusted_certs/chef-server.crt /home/vagrant/.chef/trusted_certs/chef-server.crt
```

this is not required:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

on client, update /etc/chef/client.rb . This step obviates the cert in case chef client is still failing

```
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none

/etc/chef/client.rb 
log_level        :info
log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  "https://chef-server/organizations/admin"
validation_client_name "admin-validator"
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none
```

chef-client should work